# VSCode include path error which doesn't allow me to include files from parent directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, directory, path, configuration

### Problem

I am currently trying to include another file from another directory within the parent directory. However when compiling, it gives me the error:

> C:\Programming\Projects\Implementations\Dynamic Arrary\sandbox\main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: ../include/array.h: No such file or directory
> #include <../include/array.h>

IntelliSense gives me this error:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Programming\Projects\Implementations\Dynamic Arrary\sandbox\main.cpp). C/C++(1696) cannot open source file "../include/array.h"C/C++(1696)

### What I have tried

The first thing I did was to check my include path, which was set to `${workspaceFolder}/**`, no errors there.

I then tried different methods of including the file such as `#include <./include/array.h>`, which gave the same error. I then tried `#include <include/array.h>`, which didn't work (obvious).

### Resources

The configuration file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The directory structure:

- Dynamic Array **- Parent Directory**

  - .vscode **- Subdirectories**
  - include
  - sandbox

    - main.cpp
  - src

Code within main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <include/array.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int hi {1};
    array<int> number {hi,2,3,4,5};
    number.print();
    array<double>lol{};
    array<std::string> strings {array<std::string>{"23","hi","lmao"}};
    array<std::string> strings2 {strings};
    strings.print();
    strings2.print();
}
```